# How to Display 1 Column sum in other Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a table that has different columns display different values.

I need to add a new column that displays sum of 1 column in each row of other column.

This is what i need to display. 
[image]

I have written following query but its only displaying `1` in each row of last column.

```
 select inStation.name TapInStation , outStation.name TapOutStation, 
        count(trx.passengerCount) PassengerCount, sum(trx.amount) Fare,

        (select sum(passengerCount) from transactions iTrx 
        where iTrx.ID = trx.ID) PassengerPercent                

     from transactions trx
     inner join 
     station inStation on inStation.ID = trx.fromStation 
     inner join
     station outStation on outStation.ID = trx.toStation

     GROUP BY 
     TapInStation, TapOutStation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total, then remove the correlation clause.  This may do what you want:

```
 select inStation.name as TapInStation , outStation.name as TapOutStation, 
        count(trx.passengerCount) as PassengerCount,
        sum(trx.amount) as Fare,
        (select sum(passengerCount) from transactions iTrx) as PassengerPercent
```

I'm not sure why you would called the "total" something like `PassengerPercent`, but this should return the overall total.

I also suspect that you might want a `sum()` for the previous expression.

Comment: Thanks, Its working.. Actually i need to put the percentage of each row in the `last Column`, by dividing the total sum with each row total.. but i was failing in getting the first thing right.